# Sum of elements in array using recursion even if they are string

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Have to create a function that return the sum of the element in the array but if the array is

```
["a","b","c"] // output : abc
```

So far I have

```
 function calculateSumRecursion(array) {
          //your code
          if (array.length === 0 ) {
            return 0
          }
          
      return array[0] + calculateSumRecursion(array.slice(1))
    }
```

I found out how to calculate the sum of all numbers using recursion but when it's an array of string like

```
array = ["a","b","c"]
```

it returns me

```
// abc0
```

because of the if statement.. is there any way to say

```
if (array.length === 0) return nothing instead of a 0 (that work only when it's an array of number?)
```

Comment: what means *"sum"*? please add some examples.

Comment: `+` will concatenate into a string if either side of the operator is a string.

Comment: Why return 0 if it’s not needed in the output string?

Comment: sum is [1,2,3,4,5] = 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `return` the only value in the array when the length is 1, rather than waiting until you get a length of 0. That way you are always summing compatible types (numbers or strings). Note that you still need a test for a 0 array length in case the function gets called with an empty array. In this case you need to choose what to return; as requested, it is 0.

```js
function calculateSumRecursion(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (array.length === 1) {
    return array[0];
  }
  return array[0] + calculateSumRecursion(array.slice(1))
}

console.log(calculateSumRecursion([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(calculateSumRecursion(['a', 'b', 'c']));
console.log(calculateSumRecursion([]));
```

Comment: @OP ...and if you have to define a meaning for `calculateSumRecursion([])`, add an `if (!array.length) { return appropriateValueHere; }` at the beginning. There's no way for the function to know whether you wanted `""` or `0` in that case, you'll have to pick one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks - I've updated the answer with commentary and code which deals with the situation.

Comment: this solution helped me, but i need, when array is empty , to return 0..

Comment: @YoëlZerbib I've edited the code to return 0 for an empty array

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I was searching for, thank you and soory for the confusion in my post :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5] // output : abc
let sum = calculateSumRecursion(arr);

function calculateSumRecursion (arr) {
    return arr.length ? arr.pop() + calculateSumRecursion(arr) : 0;
}
```

Slice version

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5] // output : abc
let sum = calculateSumRecursion(arr);

function calculateSumRecursion (arr) {
    return arr.length ? arr[0] + calculateSumRecursion(arr.slice(1)) : 0;
}
```

Comment: I was told to use slice() for this function, but yea I thought about pop() and its more convenient for me too :) thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

Return empty string on recursion base case. Just replace your `return 0` to `return ''`.

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
function calculateSumRecursion(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return '';
  }
  return array[0] + calculateSumRecursion(array.slice(1));
}

console.log(calculateSumRecursion(array));
```

If you are want to work with number also then check array length for zero as well as one.

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'];
const array2 = [];
const array3 = [1, 2, 3];

function calculateSumRecursion(array) {
  const rec =
    array.length === 1
      ? array[0]
      : array.length >= 1 && array[0] + calculateSumRecursion(array.slice(1));
  return array.length === 0 ? 0 : rec;
}

console.log(calculateSumRecursion(array));
console.log(calculateSumRecursion(array2));
console.log(calculateSumRecursion(array3));
```

Comment: May you add a description as to what you fixed?

Comment: The OP seems to want it to do a numeric sum when numbers are given, and string concatenation when strings are given. This doesn't do that. (But the question is also quite unclear.)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have added the description.

Comment: Your edit basically adds [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64536049/157247) into yours. Probably best not to do that. You probably weren't *copying*, but it's important to look at other answers and if someone else has already posted the correct one, just delete yours. (I do it all the time.)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to return 0 when array is empty.. is there any way to return 0 when array is empty and to return abc when array is ["a","b","c"] ?

Comment: @Yoël Zerbib now check it

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks. Yes, I had not seen it. After seeing it I have changed mine.

Answer (score 0):

Change `return 0` to `return ""` which will add an empty string to the sum.

Comment: The OP seems to want it to do a numeric sum when numbers are given, and string concatenation when strings are given. This doesn't do that. (But the question is also quite unclear.)

Comment: If the array conations numbers your code won't work and it will output a string

Answer (score 0):

You have returned `0` when the array is empty.

Now, you are doing string operations so it is needed to return empty value (not zero) so it will be affordable to return `""`.

```
function calculateSumRecursion(array) {
  return array.length === 0 ? "" : array[0] + calculateSumRecursion(array.slice(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way easier way to do this:

```
    function calculateSumRecursion(array) {
        var out = array[0];
        for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            out = out + array[i];
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: This is not [recursive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion), which is what OP is looking for

Comment: I need recursion and splice in the function